# How to make the Datatable to be editable in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on an app that takes several Xpt files as input and allows users to filter based on the column fields 'STUDYID', 'DOMAIN', and 'VALUE'. So far, everything is functioning great.

What I am looking for is that, I want to make this data table to be editable. How do achieve this?

**DATA**

**XPT1**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CR_VALUE
1           CR        1.5
2           CR        1.5
3           CR        1.5
```

**XPT2**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CM_VALUE
1           CM        1.5
2           CM        1.8
3           CR        1.9
```

**Expected Output**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CR_VALUE STATUS  COMMANDS
1           CR        1.5
2           CR        1.5
3           CR        1.5
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CM_VALUE STATUS COMMANDS
1           CM        1.5
2           CM        1.8
3           CR        1.9
```

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tables")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nms <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  suffixes <- c("STUDYID", "DOMAIN", "VALUE")
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    input$file1$datapath %>%
      map(~ read_xpt(.x))
  })
  
  # for debugging
  observe({
    print(df())
    # print(nms())
    # print(map(names(input), ~input[[.x]]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(df(), {
    nms(map(df(), names))
  })
  
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    inpts <- tagList(
      numericInput("STUDYID", "STUDYID", value = NA),
      textInput("DOMAIN", "DOMAIN", value = ""),
      numericInput("VALUE", "VALUE", value = NA)
    )
  })
  
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    map(1:length(df()), ~ tableOutput(str_c("table", .x)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$STUDYID, input$DOMAIN, input$VALUE), {
    df <- df()
   
  
    # df contains multiple dataframes so we need to loop through each of them to create the render functions
    walk(1:length(df), ~ {
      output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- renderTable({
        cur_df <- df[[.x]]
        nms <- nms()[[.x]]
        nms <- map(suffixes, ~ str_subset(nms, .)) # to order the correct column names with the required input. Warning, if more than one name matches the suffix is not tested
        # first we look if the input is character type and force a NA value on it, if it's not we just look for NA.
        # If the input is not NA (meaning that is has a value inserted by the user), then filter the table by that value.
       
        walk2(nms, suffixes, ~ {
          if (class(input[[.y]]) == "character") {
            if (input[[.y]] == "") {
              input_value <- NA
            } else {
              input_value <- input[[.y]]
            }
          } else {
            input_value <- input[[.y]]
          } # empty textInput's show has an empty string value instead of NA
          print(input_value)
          
         
          if (!is.na(input_value)) {
            cur_df <<- cur_df %>% filter(.data[[.x]] == input[[.y]])
            
          }
        })
        cur_df
        print(typeof(cur_df))
        cur_df$STATUS <- " "
        cur_df$COMMANDS <- " "
        cur_df
      })
   
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2):

`DT` provides table editing feature out of the box. You just need to do `DT::datatable(X, editable = 'cell')`. See manual with few examples [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/#:%7E:text=the%20Bootstrap%20style.-,2.3%20Table%20Editing,-You%20can%20enable)

Your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tables")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nms <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  suffixes <- c("STUDYID", "DOMAIN", "VALUE")
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    input$file1$datapath %>%
      map(~ read.table(.x, sep = "\t", header = TRUE))
  })
  
  # for debugging
  observe({
    print(df())
    # print(nms())
    # print(map(names(input), ~input[[.x]]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(df(), {
    nms(map(df(), names))
  })
  
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    inpts <- tagList(
      numericInput("STUDYID", "STUDYID", value = NA),
      textInput("DOMAIN", "DOMAIN", value = ""),
      numericInput("VALUE", "VALUE", value = NA)
    )
  })
  
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    map(1:length(df()), ~ DT::DTOutput(str_c("table", .x)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$STUDYID, input$DOMAIN, input$VALUE), {
    df <- df()
    
    
    # df contains multiple dataframes so we need to loop through each of them to create the render functions
    walk(1:length(df), ~ {
      output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- DT::renderDT({
        cur_df <- df[[.x]]
        nms <- nms()[[.x]]
        nms <- map(suffixes, ~ str_subset(nms, .)) # to order the correct column names with the required input. Warning, if more than one name matches the suffix is not tested
        # first we look if the input is character type and force a NA value on it, if it's not we just look for NA.
        # If the input is not NA (meaning that is has a value inserted by the user), then filter the table by that value.
        
        walk2(nms, suffixes, ~ {
          if (class(input[[.y]]) == "character") {
            if (input[[.y]] == "") {
              input_value <- NA
            } else {
              input_value <- input[[.y]]
            }
          } else {
            input_value <- input[[.y]]
          } # empty textInput's show has an empty string value instead of NA
          print(input_value)
          
          
          if (!is.na(input_value)) {
            cur_df <<- cur_df %>% filter(.data[[.x]] == input[[.y]])
            
          }
        })
        cur_df
        print(typeof(cur_df))
        cur_df$STATUS <- " "
        cur_df$COMMANDS <- " "
        DT::datatable(cur_df, editable = 'cell')
      })
      
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result:
[image]

Note that you can further customise editing into a particular column, row or even a collection of cells!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data, you can define it as:

```
df$STATUS <- vector1
df$COMMANDS <- vector2
```

where `vector1` and `vector2` are vectors containing the information you want.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide me with the updated code that is there in my initial post?

Comment: I have edited my post and added the updated code, Can someone help me on this?

Comment: @pawelru, Thank You.  However, once the various xpt files are uploaded, the data table result should look like "Expected output," as I described in my initial post (updated just now), but my initial code was already doing so, this way I could see my all the data tables while filtering with Domain(example) Could you please assist me with this?